# Is Earth continuously changing its orbit size i.e, circumference of the orbit?

Tags: orbital-motion, time, earth

One year have 365 days, but in leap year we have 366 days.
Does that mean earth is continuously change its orbit size for every four years.
like . 365.0 -- 365.1 -- 365.2 -- 365.3 -- 365.4 -- 365.5 -- 365.6 -- 365.7 -- 365.8 -- .... (366) ... 365.8 -- 365.7 -- 365.6 -- 365.5 -- 365.4 -- 365.3 -- 365.2 -- 365.1 -- 365.0 -- .... (355) ... 365.0 -- 365.1 -- 365.2 .... 
in this way ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence of prior effort

Comment: The possible migration of the Earth's orbit outwards would be occurring on very long time scales.  This might be $.01$AU on a time scale of $10^8$ to $10^9$ years. The leap year is done to correct for $1/4$ day error by assigning $365$ days to a year. There are other corrects as well, including leap seconds because astronomical periods are not exactly integers multiples of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's due to inaccuracy in the calendar.

In a nutshell, Earth's orbit actually takes 365 and 1/4 days. So every four years, we add an extra day so the calendar doesn't get all out of whack. Of course, it gets more interesting than that.

When I said it took 1/4 of a day longer than the calendar allows for, it actually takes a few minutes longer (11, to be precise) than a quarter of a day. So every 100 years, we don't have a leap day, again so the calendar doesn't get out of whack. But every 400 years, we still have the leap day.

Interestingly, the [Julian calendar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) had leap days, but not the 100/400 year rule, but it got out of whack (whoops) so the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) was calculated. We still use the Gregorian calendar today - it repeats every 400 years and has 97 leap days in each cycle. Finally, this only applies for solar calendars...lunar calendars add a leap month, and only gets weirder from there. Oh, and even more interesting: in the [Chinese calendar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_calendar), leap days only occur in the year of the dragon, rat, and monkey.

Hope this helps!

More information can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29).

Comment: dragon, rat, and monkey.
you are wonderful 
i was looking for these for many days

Comment: You were specifically looking for the years of the dragon, rat, and monkey?

Comment: No, am actually looking for their species ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think we have answered the question, I am just not sure exactly what it is :)       Nani, I'm glad you got an answer, but could you tell us what animals have to do with it?

Comment: @count_to_10, agreed. =)

Comment: You probably game me 13th Dimension, 7th Dimension and 3rd dimension species details according to Chinese old science .
which i was itching my head form days to arrange these species according to its dimensions .

Comment: @NaniHari, I'm sorry, but I'm still confused. Dimensions, animals, leap year...what's the connection?

Comment: @NaniHari What are asking we r not able to figure out what u r asking literally, I'm staring at my screen rght now

Comment: Bingo!!!!......sort of :  Chinese calender  has a leap year every 3 years. http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/chinese-zodiac-signs.html

Comment: Job done, going back to physics.....enough to be curious about there.

Comment: No not exactly ...
it would be little complicated to explain form for me now,
coz i really don't know that terminology in english that can make you understand what i am looking after .

Comment: Ohh I c so is it actually what count_to_10 have spoted out and what is that troubling u

Comment: All i can say is,
i am actually looking after Infinity point for every  dimensional plane. 
which would be little difficult for me to explain right now every thing in english.
all the information i am gathering is related to expansion and contraction of our universe , if it really exists .
This look silly if i explain it without any theoretical prof .

Comment: i actually forgot .

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [Wikipedia Leap year](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)

> A common year has 365 days and a leap year 366 days, with the extra, or intercalary,day designated as February 29. A leap year occurs every four years to help synchronize the calendar year with the solar year, or the length of time it takes the earth to complete its orbit about the sun, which is about 365¼ days.

[image]

So the the earth's orbit does not change every 4 years, although over much, much longer time periods it has changed  and it will change in the future.

Comment: then i will be applying my formula here
it starts like 365.241 -- 365.242 .... 366... 365.242 -- 365.241 --365.24 -- ........

Answer (score 0):

**Is Earth's orbit changing?**

*Yes. But not large enough to alter our calendar in near future*

Well, there are some long-period oscillations, but those are very small, and don't imply that we're systematically moving towards or away from the Sun.

From [Ask An Astronomer](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/41-our-solar-system/the-earth/orbit/83-is-the-distance-from-the-earth-to-the-sun-changing-advanced):

> There is an effect which is making us move very slowly away from the Sun. That is the tidal interaction between the Sun and the Earth. This slows down the rotation of the Sun, and pushes the Earth farther away from the Sun. The principle for the Sun-Earth system should be the same. But how big of an effect is this? It turns out that the yearly increase in the distance between the Earth and the Sun from this effect is only about one micrometer (a millionth of a meter, or a ten thousandth of a centimeter). So this is a very tiny effect.

The following describes why the leap years are made:

from [infoplease.com](http://www.infoplease.com/spot/leapyear1.html)

> The [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), which now serves as the standard calendar for civil use throughout the world, has both common years and leap years. A common year has 365 days and a leap year 366 days, with the extra, or intercalar, day designated as February 29. A leap year occurs every four years to help synchronize the calendar year with the solar year, or the length of time it takes the earth to complete its orbit about the sun, which is about 365¼ days.
>
> The length of the solar year, however, is slightly less than 365¼ days—by about 11 minutes. To compensate for this discrepancy, the leap year is omitted three times every four hundred years.
>
> In other words, a century year cannot be a leap year unless it is divisible by 400. Thus 1700, 1800, and 1900 were not leap years, but 1600, 2000, and 2400 are leap years.

This CPG Grey's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX96xng7sAE) might be helpful

If you got some time to spare this Vsauce [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJhgZBn-LHg&feature=youtu.be&t=1) will be lot informatory, its just awesome

Comment: so 1/146000th will be an extra day for every 1 year of 365 days .

Answer (score 0):

The Earth's orbit remains pretty much the same from year to year.  Each year takes the same amount of time - about 365.24 x 24 hours.  The trouble for calendar makers is that this is not a whole number of days.  If we just rounded it off to the nearest day then, over time, New Year's Day would arrive a bit earlier each year compared to the seasons.  For example this year the winter solstice will occur 11 days before New Year's Day.  If every year had 365 days then in 20 years the solstice would occur 6 days before New Year's Day.  To fix this we add five extra days - one every 4 years.

Since the length of the year is not exactly 365.25 days further adjustments have to be made. For example every 100 years we don't have a leap year when you would normally expect one (unless the year is also divisible by 400 in which case we do).

Comment: 400 years = 1 leap year =365days.
365 day makes one rotation 
146000 days makes 400 rotation 
in which 1 to 200 rotations are increasing orbits size and 200 to 400 are decreasing it size 
There is a change.